# Custom class not working with x:Bind in UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have the following class:

```
namespace MainProject.Model
{
   public class ModelObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
     public int Value{ get; set; }
   }
}
```

I try to use it in my template with `x:Bind`:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate" x:DataType="model:ModelObject">
    <my:CustomSelector Grid.Column="1" ActualValue="{x:Bind Value}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

On build I always get this message:

> XBF syntax error '0x09C4' : Property Not Found. Check if the property
>   you are setting in XAML exists in the minimum version of the platform
>   being specified in the project (TargetPlatformMinVersion)

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ffd8d90-28f5-49f0-ac80-a435c0b3bffc/xbf-syntax-error-0x09c4?forum=wpdevelop), I have to set the Minimum Version of Windows, and I did that:

[image]

I also tried to create a local descendant in the main project instead of the model project to make the namespaces the same:

```
namespace MainProject.UWP
  {
       public class UWPModelObject: ModelObject
      {
      }
  }
```

What else should I do?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230952/using-xbind-inside-the-gridviews-itemtemplate-layout-user-control-in-uwp

Comment: `Value` is an overused name. To be totally safe, use something else. Also dive into the code and error to find out which property isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ModelObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int DaValue
    {
        get { return _daValue; }
        set
        {
            _daValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _daValue;




    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Is int the right type? Or should you use string!?

EDIT: In the MainPage.cs set the datacontext like this:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ModelObject modelObject = new ModelObject();
        DataContext = modelObject;
    }
```